# How can i avoid spaming my Console with the OnMouseOver Function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code works, but is there a possibility that the OnMouseOver function does not spam the Console? I'm always open to suggestions for improvement Thx. :3

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoverButton : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    private bool Hovering = false;

    private void OnMouseOver() 
    {
        Hovering = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Hovering)
        {
            Collider2D HoveringButton = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePos);

            if(HoveringButton)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hi");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a flag so you only log once and reset the flag when the mouse moves away. Not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: remove the line             Debug.Log("Hi");

Comment: The "Hi" is just an example i want to make an animation with it but thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a possibility that the OnMouseOver function does not spam the Console

Yes: Don't log something every frame => Add some condition checks that log only once.

---

Anyway, you rather want to use

```
private bool hovering;

private void OnMouseEnter() 
{
    hovering = true;
    Debug.Log("Hi");
}

private void OnMouseExit() 
{
    hovering = false;
}
```

otherwise the `Hovering` would never be reset to false.

---

The `Physics2D.OverlapPoint` seems quite redundant since if `OnMouseEnter` is called it already means that your current mouse position is overlapping this object's collider.

**IF** - for whatever reason - you then still need to do this anyway, you could simply store the current hit and compare like e.g.

```
private bool hovering;

private Collider2D currentHoveringButton;

private void Update()
{
    if(!hovering) return;

    var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    var hoveringButton = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePos);

    if(hoveringButton && hoveringButton != currentHoveringButton)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hi");
    }
    
    currentHoveringButton = hoveringButton;
}
```

Comment: but dont i have to connect the OnMouseEnter Function with my Button?

Comment: @NunjaUwU no, why? `OnMouseEnter` is called if the mouse enters this object's collider so why would you make another overlap check if you already know that the mouse is hovering the button?

Comment: i tryed it, works perfectly thanks a lot